# iTextSharp is not working with foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I'm trying to insert images to a pdf file and this code is working right without foreach loop, but not working with foreach loop. Positions of images (top, left) are saved in data base, so foreach loop is getting positions of images and then placing them dynamically. But when I use foreach loop this code is not working, if I give static position to image to be inserted in pdf file, it works fine then.
And I have to place multiple imges that's why i'm using foreach loop and positions of images will be dynamic so it's must to use foreach loop.
And one more problem in this code is that it's just exporting first page of pdf file, instead I want to export all pages of pdf file i.e. complete pdf document with images. Anyone here help me to sort out this problem

```
        string pdfFile = Server.MapPath("~/files/" + arg);

        ViewBag.file = pdfFile;

        var getAllPostitions = db.DraggedElements.Where(l => l.doc_name == arg).ToList();
        ViewBag.tag_positions = getAllPostitions;

        string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/images/sign.png");
        string DEST = @"e:/TestComplete.pdf";
        //string IMG = @"C:Saved//TestImage.JPG";
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfFile);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(Size);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(DEST, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter weiter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = weiter.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        iTextSharp.text.Image signImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
        signImg.ScaleToFit(50, 50);
        foreach (var position in getAllPostitions)
        {
            string topStr = position.top;
            string topStr1 = topStr.Split(':')[1];
            string topStr2 = topStr1.Split('p')[0];
            float top = float.Parse(topStr2);

            string leftStr = position.left;
            string leftStr1 = leftStr.Split(':')[1];
            string leftStr2 = leftStr1.Split('p')[0];
            float left = float.Parse(leftStr2);
            signImg.SetAbsolutePosition(top, left);
            document.Add(signImg);
        }
        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        weiter.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: Your best bet will be to set a breakpoint on your foreach loop and step through each line watching the variables to see how they change. It could easily be that the getAllPositions variable doesn't have the data the way that you plan.

Comment: I have debugged my code, it is giving all positions correctly.

Comment: Can you define what "not working" means? 

Does it do something like only put 1 image on the page? If so, you may attempt to move your signImg creation and initialization into the loop (I am curious if the document.add works by reference rather than by value).

Comment: not woking means that it's not inserting images in pdf document

Comment: *"one more problem in this code is that it's just exporting first page of pdf file, instead I want to export all pages of pdf file"* - your code creates only a single page. So I don't understand your remark.

Comment: `signImg.SetAbsolutePosition(top, left)` - if I remember correctly that method expects the coordinates if the *bottom* left corner. You know that the origin of the coordinate system in pdfs usually is in the bottom left corner...?

Comment: yes @mkl issue is this, how can I correct it?

Comment: Simply use the bottom left coordinates in the PDF default user space coordinate system.